# Tried minting from transition in StateMachine an got error MintingPolicyNotFound

Tags: plutus, minting, statemachines

I changed [transition function in Lecture 7](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-pioneer-program/blob/1ab1d5c11a94da0b709ad05f921d91795a2fc209/code/week08/src/Week08/TokenSale.hs#L63) and added constraint for minting Constraints.mustMintValue:

```
transition ts s r = case (stateValue s, stateData s, r) of
    (v, _, SetPrice p)   | p >= 0           -> Just ( Constraints.mustBeSignedBy (tsSeller ts) <>
                                                      Constraints.mustMintValue (assetClassValue (tsToken ts) 100)
                                                    , State p v
                                                    )
```

When I start emulator trace monad I am getting error in log:

```
Slot 00007: *** CONTRACT LOG: "SMCContractError (ConstraintResolutionError (MintingPolicyNotFound aa))"
```

I tried also with a different currencyPolicy than "aa", the real one that I got from Lecture 5 - Free.hs but I am getting the same result.

What is the proper way to do minting from State Machine?

Comment: HI , Did you solve this issue.? I am Facing the same issue

Comment: Try adding a lookup specifying a minting policy. Not sure how to do it in the StateMachine context, but elsewhere I did something like: `let lookups = Constraints.mintingPolicy (policy oref)`.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same issue with a StateMachine. I solved it by using `runStepWith` instead of `runStep`, which allows you to also supply the minting policy.

See [the haddock documentation](https://playground.plutus.iohkdev.io/doc/haddock/plutus-contract/html/Plutus-Contract-StateMachine.html#:%7E:text=lookups%20for%20transaction.-,runStepWith,Source,-%23) for details on how to use `runStepWith`